# How to query in mongodb to search text?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a sentence like "How can I help you?" and in my mongodb data is save like :

```
[{
 "word" :"Hello"
},{
"word" :"How"
},{
"word" :"can"
},
{
"word" :"I help you?"
},{
"word" :"I can't help you?"
}]
```

So, I want like whenever I search a sentence it will come with result where my sentence words are exists in mongo documents and sort on the basis more words match.
The result should be like :

```
  [{
    "word" :"I help you?"
    },{
    "word" :"How"
    },{
    "word" :"can"
  }]
```

Comment: Mongodb is no good at full context search, you are probably  need ElasticSearch.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/ may be sufficient. It's not as flexible as ES, but does the job in some cases.